# How to set size for html.TextBox helper?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to set size for html.TextBox helper in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code might help you out

```
<%=Html.TextBox("test", null, new { style="width:50px" })%>
```

Please provide the version of mvc. The code has minor changes for all 3 versions. The above one is for mvc2.

Answer (score 2):

One of the overload for Html.TextBox provides mechanism for assigning attribute values to textbox. With this you can set not only size but also all other htmlattributes like class, maxlength etc.

```
Html.TextBox( "textboxname", null, new { @size = "size" } )
```

Here last parameter is an object for specifying the html attributes.

You can look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049.aspx) for more details.